# AWS Elastic Beanstalk option_settings env variable with instance ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am deploying an application using the [Elastic Beanstalk Go Platform](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/go-environment.html).

**I need to set an environment variable for the current private ip of the instance.** (I need this environment variable to be available to my app itself, once it's run via `Procfile`.)

In my `.ebextensions/options.config` file I've tried everything but no luck yet:

```
{
  "option_settings": [
    {
      "namespace": "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment",
      "option_name": "PRIVATE_IP",
      "value": {
        "Fn::GetAtt": [
          "Ec2Instance",
          "PrivateIp"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

This example sets `PRIVATE_IP` to literally the entire `Fn::GetAtt...` json string. Are functions not interpreted in `option_settings`? Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how you would implement this solution in .ebextensions, but AWS has a special URL, http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/, that you can use to request this information. Check for more info [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). For the IP address you can use http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4. This URL check the http origin and respond with information of your instance.

I think you can configure your YAML to make a curl request and get the data. But maybe you don't need to save this info at deployment time because the URL is available for your instance at runtime. You can make this request directly in your code.

Comment: The private IP is available too. For it you use local-ipv4 as a resource name.

Comment: Gustavo, thanks. I'm aware of that endpoint but curl was not actually executed in yaml. For some specific reasons I do need the ip available in an env variable before the app is first run.

Comment: That resource info isn't available in ebextensions in Beanstalk, only Cloudformation. To create an env variable with the ip address, you'd have to get it from metadata, then issue a container_command to update it using the locally installed aws cli.